# nvd3 Multibar-Chart - not stacked

Tags: nvd3.js

I have no clue, why my data stream is not working correctly. I have 2 data-streams. One with negative values and one with positive values.
The problem is, that stream 2 (blue bars) is not starting at the zero line in my chart. The bars are much to height - around 200px (hidden downwards)
Did someone have an idea why this happens? Could it be the cause, that the streams are not equal?

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart();

chart.xAxis
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

chart.yAxis
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));

chart.multibar.stacked(true); // default to stacked
chart.showControls(false); // don't show controls

d3.select('#chart svg')
    .datum(myData.uas.data)
  .transition().duration(500).call(chart);

nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

return chart;
```

});

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ls007/egy89y6m/7/#&togetherjs=bbvSxE9kbj)

Hope someone could give me a hint.

Cheers K.